# deferred promise returning to variable angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, deferred

Is there a way I can achieve this where `toys` is a deferred API request and when run the value of `res` is returned and is the end result for when `toysData` is logged.

**the promise**

```
const toys = (url) => {
  const deferred = $q.defer();
  const params = {
    id: url,
  };

  ToysModel.get(params, (data) => {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  }, (error) => {
    deferred.reject(error);
  });
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

**the request**

```
let toysData = toys(uuid)
    .then(res => res);

console.log(toysData);
```

**api call**

```
export default class ToysModel {
  constructor($resource, ENV) {
    const url = `${ENV.apiEndpoint}/`;

    const actions = {
      oembed: {
        url: `${ENV.apiEndpoint}/toy/:id`,
        method: 'get',
        params: {
          id: '@id',
        },
        crossDomain: true,
      },
    };
    return $resource(url, {}, actions);
  }
}
```

Comment: The console.log goes inside the .then

Answer (score 0):

that variable toysData would have promise object. It mens that you can subscribe to success or fail state. If you want to log response you just need to subscribe on success state with log function

```
toys(uuid).then(console.log);
```